# Unique constraint to database table gets error: "ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry for key"

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

have a newly created MySQL table and trying to add a unique constraint on one of the columns (phone_number), but I keep getting the following error:

"ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry for..."

Attached screenshot of the table and also output.

Forgot to make sure records are unique based on phone number and now trying to remedy this.

Any idea on why this error is showing and how we can still add a unique constraint? Thanks

[image: MYSQL TABLES]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find duplicates

`SELECT phone_number, COUNT(*) c FROM leads GROUP BY phone_number HAVING c > 1;`

Get rid of duplicates and then unique constraint will work.